# The data alone is missing when I try to send from Angular.js to Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, http, multipartform-data

I am trying to send data from my `Angular.js` controller to `Node.js` backend. I succeeded in making a `MongoDB` entry when the request is raised.But the data is missing in the MongoDB entry. I am stuck and can't proceed with my app anymore. Can anyone give me a clear explanation why I am not able to send the form data to the `Node.js`.

I had put my schema of the data here:

```
var common = require('../common');

var inviteeSchema = common.Schema({
    email: String
}); 
var Invite = common.conn.model('Invite', inviteeSchema);
module.exports = Invite;
```

I have enclosed the routing code here.

```
router.route('/addtoinvitelist').post(function (req, res, next) {

var invite =new Invite(req.body);

invite.save(function(err,email){
   if(err) throw err;

    res.json({message:"your mail id is stored in our database we will soon send you an invite"})
});
});
```

My HTML form goes here

```
<form action="#">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="subcribeNewsletter" class="control-label">INVITE FORM<br> <small>We are happy to invite you to medicoshere, So please enter your email ID in the below form.</small></label>
                                                <div class="input-group input-group-in input-group-sm">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope text-belpet"></i></div>
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="subcribeNewsletter" placeholder="name@mail.com" ng-model="useremail" required>
                                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-belpet" ng-click="AddToInviteList(useremail)"><strong>OK</strong></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                        </form><!-- /form -->
```

my angular service functions goes here 
`this.AddToInviteList = function (email, cb) {

```
    $http({

        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:3000/users/addtoinvitelist",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }, // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        data:"email"

    }).success(function (data) {

        console.log("email is posted sucessfully" + data);
        cb(data);
    })

}`
```

Controller function is here

```
App.controller('InviteController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, UserServices) {
$scope.init = function () {
    console.log("hii this is a test ")
};


$scope.email = {};

$scope.AddToInviteList = function () {

    UserServices.AddToInviteList($scope.email, function (dataresponse) {


        console.log(dataresponse);

    })

}
```

});

Comment: Are you getting `email` value in backend?

Comment: Yes an empty string in the database...

Comment: Because you are sending as static `email` as string so pass in body with `data:email`

Comment: If i give data:email then there is no entry of email in database  only object id is coming into database...

Comment: what are you getting value in `req.body.email`?

Comment: its logging as "undefined".....!

Comment: yes, change `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` at request time

Comment: Your model name is 'useremail' but you are passing '$scope.email' in to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Pass email as json object { 'email' : email }.

Just try this code:

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:3000/users/addtoinvitelist",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data:{ 'email' : email }

  }).success(function (data) {

    console.log("email is posted sucessfully" + data);
    cb(data);
  })
```

Controller :

```
App.controller('InviteController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, UserServices) {
$scope.init = function () {
    console.log("hii this is a test ")
};

$scope.AddToInviteList = function () {
    $scope.user = {
       email : $scope.useremail
    };

    UserServices.AddToInviteList($scope.user, function (dataresponse) {
      console.log(dataresponse);
    })
   }
});
```

In server side you can access the email by calling 'req.body.email'

Answer (score 0):

Change your `model` name in `HTML input element` with `email` and send `request` as

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:3000/users/addtoinvitelist",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data:{ 'email' : email }

  }).success(function (data) {

    console.log("email is posted sucessfully" + data);
    cb(data);
  })
```

and get it at backend side as

`req.body.email`

I think that should work!

**Update**

```
App.controller('InviteController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, UserServices) {
$scope.init = function () {
    console.log("hii this is a test ")
};


$scope.AddToInviteList = function () {

    UserServices.AddToInviteList($scope.email, function (dataresponse) {


        console.log(dataresponse);

    })

}
```

Comment: Did you change your `ng-model="useremail"` as `ng-model="email"` ?

Comment: Yes did all thing you suggested but it becomes undefined..... Dunno why....iam stuck up..

Comment: Are you getting proper `email` value in your angular controller?

Comment: No where iam getting the email value.... all wer its undefined.... both angular and node says its undefined....!

Comment: remove your `$scope.email = {};` this line from your controller and then print `console.log($scope.email)`.
If you are getting then I think it must be work

Comment: yes iam getting right value upto service but not in the db... I am sure the mystery is lying in compiling and parsing of data....  if i give `{
    "email":"nivas@123.com"
}` in postman its perfectly fiting in....

Comment: Mean you are still getting `undefined` in `req.body.email`?
Did you use 

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`
in your server file

Comment: Can you show the `console.log(req.body)` value in your `router` ?

Comment: `undefined
POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 4.564 ms - 84
undefined
POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 6.812 ms - 84
undefined
POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 8.442 ms - 84

POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 4.908 ms - 84
undefined
POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 5.228 ms - 84
undefined
POST /users/addtoinvitelist 200 4.865 ms - 84`